# Auto update for web app as a service with no launcher

Tags: install4j

Does auto update functionality in install4j work if the the app is a web app as a service which has no launcher? I have tried many ways mentioned in web resources but no luck. Please help. I am using install4j Windows Edition 6.1.6.

Edit 1:
@Ingo Kegel, 
            I added `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log.txt` as per your suggestion and got the below log. Please help.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 630]: Execute action
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_38
       Property variableName: updateDescriptorEntry
       Property failIfNull: true
       Property onlyIfUndefined: false
       Property responseFileVariable: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 630]: Execute action not successful after 4 ms
```

**EDIT 2:**
Below are the logs after executing code (After the exe file has been downloaded)
`UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q"), false, null);`

**Logs:**

```
 [INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.CheckForUpdateAction [ID 629]: Execute action
   Property connectTimeout: 10000
   Property connectionFailureScript: null
   Property readTimeout: 20000
   Property requestHeaders: []
   Property url: http://localhost:8181/astra-downloads/updates.xml
   Property variable: updateDescriptor
   Property acceptAllCertificates: false
   Property askForProxy: true
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Property showError: true
   Download: http://localhost:8181/astra-downloads/updates.xml to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\i4jupd4650856858406689282.xml; size: 366 bytes
   Variable changed: updateDescriptor=com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorImpl@82c94f[class com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorImpl]
   Execute action successful after 44 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 630]: Execute action
   Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_63
   Property variableName: updateDescriptorEntry
   Property failIfNull: true
   Property onlyIfUndefined: false
   Property responseFileVariable: false
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Branch 1
   3.0.1
   Variable changed: updateDescriptorEntry=UpdateDescriptorEntry [target: 22, file: GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe][class com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorEntryImpl]
   Execute action successful after 4 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 632]: Execute action
   Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_65
   Property variableName: updaterNewVersion
   Property failIfNull: false
   Property onlyIfUndefined: false
   Property responseFileVariable: false
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Variable changed: updaterNewVersion=3.0.1[class java.lang.String]
   Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 633]: Execute action
   Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_66
   Property variableName: updaterDownloadUrl
   Property failIfNull: false
   Property onlyIfUndefined: false
   Property responseFileVariable: false
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Variable changed: updaterDownloadUrl=http://localhost:8181/astra-downloads/GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe[class java.lang.String]
   Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 634]: Execute action
   Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_67
   Property variableName: updaterDownloadFile
   Property failIfNull: false
   Property onlyIfUndefined: false
   Property responseFileVariable: false
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Variable changed: updaterDownloadFile=C:/Users/Abhishek/Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe[class java.lang.String]
   Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.net.DownloadFileAction [ID 635]: Execute action
   Property connectTimeout: 10000
   Property connectionFailureScript: null
   Property md5Url: 
   Property readTimeout: 20000
   Property requestHeaders: []
   Property targetFile: C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe
   Property url: http://localhost:8181/astra-downloads/GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe
   Property acceptAllCertificates: false
   Property askForProxy: true
   Property checkForMd5Sums: false
   Property deleteOnExit: false
   Property dontAskForRetry: false
   Property retryIfInterrupted: true
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Property showError: true
   Property showFileName: true
   Property showProgress: true
   Download: http://localhost:8181/astra-downloads/GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe to C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe; size: 43569152 bytes
   Execute action successful after 2640 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.SetModeAction [ID 637]: Execute action
   Property directoryFilter: null
   Property fileFilter: null
   Property fileTarget: everything
   Property files: [C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe]
   Property filesRoot: null
   Property mode: 755
   Property recursive: false
   Property rollbackSupported: true
   Property showFileNames: true
   Property showProgress: false
   Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.ScheduleUpdateAction [ID 638]: Execute action
   Property arguments: []
   Property installerFile: C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe
   Property maxCancelCount: 10
   Property maxTries: 3
   Property version: 3.0.1
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Execute action successful after 3 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen [ID 627]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] cleaning up
[INFO] Finished
```

**EDIT 3:**
Below is the logs of `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q","-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true","-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log2.txt"), false, null);`

```
[INFO] logger started at Fri Sep 15 15:27:01 IST 2017
[INFO] executable name: C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe
[INFO] install4j version: 6.1.6 (build 6459)
[INFO] Properties: 
-- listing properties --
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
exe4j.moduleName=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAs...
sun.boot.library.path=c:\windows\temp\e4j101b.tmp_dir150546...
exe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_users_abhishek_downloads_gre...
java.vm.version=24.80-b11
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=;
exe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.script=
user.country=US
sun.os.patch.level=
install4j.exeDir=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j101B.tmp_dir150546...
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_80-b15
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\windows\temp\e4j101b.tmp_dir150546...
os.arch=x86
java.io.tmpdir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.variant=
exe4j.tempDir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j101B.tmp_dir150546...
os.name=Windows NT (unknown)
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j101B.tmp_dir150546...
sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons=true
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=51.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
install4j.language=en
exe4j.isInstall4j=true
os.version=10.0
install4j.updateStorageDir=C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprof...
user.home=C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
user.timezone=Asia/Calcutta
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.specification.version=1.7
file.encoding=Cp1252
user.name=ABHISHEK-PC$
java.class.path=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j101B.tmp_dir150546...
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
sun.arch.data.model=32
java.home=c:\windows\temp\e4j101b.tmp_dir150546...
sun.java.command=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAs...
exe4j.launchName=C:\Users\Abhishek\DOWNLO~1\GREYTI~1.EXE
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.language=en
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
exe4j.unextractedPosition=26515602
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.ext.dirs=c:\windows\temp\e4j101b.tmp_dir150546...
sun.boot.class.path=c:\windows\temp\e4j101b.tmp_dir150546...
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
install4j.appDir=C:\Windows\Temp\
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
install4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log2.txt
install4j.lockFile=C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprof...
install4j.keepLog=true
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+m...
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction [ID 304]: Execute action
       Property allRequested: false
       Property failIfNotRootUnix: true
       Property obtainIfAdminMac: false
       Property obtainIfNormalWin: false
       Property obtainIfNormalMac: false
       Property obtainIfAdminWin: true
       Property failIfNotObtainedWin: true
       Property failIfNotObtainedMac: true
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Execute action successful after 1 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen [ID 1]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.WelcomeScreen [ID 2]: Show screen
[INFO] checking writable with maximum
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.WelcomeScreen [ID 2]: thread name AWT-EventQueue-0
```

[image]

**EDIT 4:**
My code in Application:

```
try {
        ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("626", null, false, new ApplicationLauncher.Callback() {
                public void exited(int exitValue) {
                    //TODO add your code here (not invoked on event dispatch thread)
                    log.debug("******Exited "+exitValue+"********");
                    log.debug("****Inside block UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled() "+String.valueOf(UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()));

                    boolean updateScheduled=UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled();


                    if(updateScheduled){
                        log.debug("***************Running UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate*******************");
                        UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q","-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true","-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log2.txt"), false, null);
                        log.debug("***************Completed UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate*******************");
                    }
                }

                public void prepareShutdown() {
                    //TODO add your code here (not invoked on event dispatch thread)
                    log.debug("******prepare shut down********");
                }
            }
        );

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO handle invocation failure
    }
```

And the jstack error is as below:
[image]

**EDIT 5:**
Below is the jstack log:

```
    2017-09-18 17:31:12
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode):

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x17ecec00 nid=0x3708 waiting on condition [0x1861f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x03850980> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x03884b18> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x17d3f000 nid=0x2670 waiting on condition [0x1841e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x08ca4218> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x17d2fc00 nid=0x40c runnable [0x1838f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x17d2f400 nid=0xe68 in Object.wait() [0x182ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x08c79758> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x08c79758> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x17d2ec00 nid=0x3d64 in Object.wait() [0x1826f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x08c797e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x08c797e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x1783bc00 nid=0x468 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x1783a000 nid=0x1768 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x17837800 nid=0x389c waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x17835400 nid=0x3258 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x0101a800 nid=0x4394 in Object.wait() [0x033bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x08ab74f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x08ab74f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01015800 nid=0x3d50 in Object.wait() [0x0127f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x08ab7588> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x08ab7588> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=6 tid=0x010ac400 nid=0x3138 in Object.wait() [0x00798000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x038517d0> (a com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.CommandSink)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:87)
    - locked <0x038517d0> (a com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.CommandSink)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:59)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01012400 nid=0x1bf0 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x17856000 nid=0x2fdc waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 449
```

**EDIT 6:**
Below is the log of `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q","-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true","-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log2.txt"), false, null);`:

```
[INFO] logger started at Tue Sep 19 11:20:00 IST 2017
[INFO] executable name: C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe
[INFO] install4j version: 7.0.1 (build 7043)
[INFO] Properties: 
-- listing properties --
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
exe4j.moduleName=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAs...
sun.boot.library.path=c:\windows\temp\e4j554d.tmp_dir150580...
exe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_users_abhishek_downloads_gre...
java.vm.version=24.80-b11
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=;
exe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.script=
user.country=US
sun.os.patch.level=
install4j.exeDir=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j554D.tmp_dir150580...
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_80-b15
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\windows\temp\e4j554d.tmp_dir150580...
os.arch=x86
java.io.tmpdir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.variant=
exe4j.tempDir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j554D.tmp_dir150580...
os.name=Windows NT (unknown)
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j554D.tmp_dir150580...
sun.awt.enableExtraMouseButtons=true
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=51.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
install4j.language=en
exe4j.isInstall4j=true
os.version=10.0
install4j.updateStorageDir=C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprof...
user.home=C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
user.timezone=Asia/Calcutta
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.specification.version=1.7
file.encoding=Cp1252
user.name=ABHISHEK-PC$
java.class.path=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\e4j554D.tmp_dir150580...
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
sun.arch.data.model=32
java.home=c:\windows\temp\e4j554d.tmp_dir150580...
sun.java.command=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\GreytipAs...
exe4j.launchName=C:\Users\Abhishek\DOWNLO~1\GREYTI~1.EXE
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.language=en
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
exe4j.unextractedPosition=25300990
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.ext.dirs=c:\windows\temp\e4j554d.tmp_dir150580...
sun.boot.class.path=c:\windows\temp\e4j554d.tmp_dir150580...
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
install4j.appDir=C:\Windows\Temp\
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
install4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log2.txt
install4j.lockFile=C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprof...
install4j.keepLog=true
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+m...
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction [ID 304]: Execute action
       Property allRequested: false
       Property failIfNotObtainedMac: true
       Property failIfNotObtainedWin: true
       Property failIfNotRootUnix: true
       Property obtainIfAdminMac: false
       Property obtainIfAdminWin: true
       Property obtainIfNormalMac: false
       Property obtainIfNormalWin: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property updateInstallationDirectory: true
       Execute action successful after 1 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen [ID 1]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.WelcomeScreen [ID 2]: Show screen
[INFO] checking writable with maximum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend updating to install4j 7 which has a lot of new auto-update functionality which works well for services.

With install4j 7, you add a "Background update downloader" application on the Installer->Screen & Actions step. The key action in that application template is the "Schedule update installation" action.

In your service, you launch the update downloader like this:

```
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("<ID>", null, true, null);
```

in its own thread where `<ID>` is replaced with the ID of the application. This call blocks and when it returns an update installer may have been downloaded. You can check this condition with

```
UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()
```

Now you only need to trigger the execution of the downloaded installer. You can either do that immediately, or at startup if you do not want to terminate the service. The code snippet you need is this:

```
UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q"), false, null);
```

As part of the update installation, services are shut down. Services cannot auto-restart (which GUI launchers could do if you passed `true` as the second parameter to the above method call) but have to be started with a "Start a service" action which you probably already have in your installer.

For more information and screen shots, see

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/whatsnew7.html

and search for "Background auto-update".

Comment: How to know the  ID of the application? I am asking this because I have a confusion between the one generated with programmatic Integration wizard (which says 354) and the one displayed in Update Options screen->Application ID (which says 9244-5699-2766-7401)

Comment: The ID of the downloader application is the one you see on the Installer->Screens & Actions step, next to the name of the update downloader application, if you select the "Show IDs" tool bar button. The other ID that you mentioned (9244-5699-2766-7401) is the ID of the project.

Comment: And what is the default download location for the new media file. I don't understand this value 'context.getVariable("sys.updateStorageDir") + File.separator + ((UpdateDescriptorEntry)context.getVariable("updateDescriptorEntry")).getFileName()'

Comment: And also I tried with install4j 7.0.1 but no luck I have called ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("626", null, false, new ApplicationLauncher.Callback() {}) Its not downloading the new media file uploaded to web server.

Comment: Note: There is no launcher for my app

Comment: You should not have to worry about the download location. Please see the the log file of the update downloader to check what happens.  Pass the VM parameters `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=/path/to/writable/log.txt` to the update downloader (the second parameter of `launchApplication` takes a string array with parameters) in order get that log file in a particular path.

Comment: I have added the logs I got in log file in question section under 'Edit 1'. Please help. updateDescriptorEntry is not executing successfully.

Comment: There is probably no update in the downloaded updates.xml meaning that the version is the same as the already installed version.

Comment: No there is an update. Existing version is 3.0.0 and the new version in web server which i have uploaded is 3.0.1 and I am able to access http://localhost:8181/astra-downloads/updates.xml and also the exe file with appropriate url

Comment: You would then have to edit the script of the "Set a variable" action and add debugging code like this `Util.logInfo(null, "Branch 1");` to see why the action does not return an update descriptor entry. To log the versions of the available entries, execute `UpdateDescriptorEntry[] entries = ((UpdateDescriptor)context.getVariable("updateDescriptor")).getEntries();
for (UpdateDescriptorEntry entry : entries) {
    Util.logInfo(null, entry.getNewVersion());
}
`

Comment: I was able to see 3.0.1 in logs and now the .exe file is being downloaded but after executing `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q"), false, null);` My app is not getting updated ( But as said by you the current running app is being stopped as its a service). I have added the logs in the question as **EDIT 2**. Kindly help.

Comment: Now it looks good. In your application what does `UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()` return after the update downloader has downloaded the new update? Try adding arguments `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=/path/to/writable/log.txt` to the `executeScheduledUpdate` call as additional arguments to the `Arrays.asList` expression to see the log file of the executed installer.

Comment: `UpdateChecker.isUpdateScheduled()` returns true and I have added the logs of `executeScheduledUpdate` in question as **EDIT3**. I also see the new installer being executed in command prompt with the help of **Process Explorer** app. I have also attached screenshot of it. Kindly help.

Comment: Actually this looks like the the installer is running in GUI mode and the "Welcome" screen is being displayed. Are you sure you are still passing the "-q" flag? Please use the jstack tool from the JDK to get a stack trace from the installer.

Comment: My Code: `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q","-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true","-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/log2.txt"), false, null);`  For full code I have added it as **EDIT 4** in question. Also I am not able to get any log using jstack. I am getting error `Unable to attach to 32-bit process running under WOW64`. Please check **EDIT 4** for details

Comment: It seems that the installer is running with a 32-bit JRE. You have to use jstack from a 32-bit JDK, not from a 64-bit JDK.

Comment: I have added the jstack log in question as **EDIT 5**. Kindly help.

Comment: The update installer that is being executed has been created with install4j 6. You have to create that installer with install4j 7 as well.

Comment: I generated new exe file of version 3.0.1 (installer) with  install4j 7 and placed in web server. Yet no luck getting same jstack log and looking at the log of `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate` it still looks like its showing up welcome screen. I have added the logs as **EDIT6** in question. Kindly help.

Comment: Yes, the installer seems to be running in GUI mode. The installer has a "Allow unattended mode" property that must be selected (it is selected by default), please check that. What if you execute the installer manually from the command line with the same arguments? Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately some how option "Allow unattended mode" was not ticked. Now Auto Update is happening. Happy about it :).But when i see the installation folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra` the new installer is not removing the redundant jar file of old version (asca-3.0.0.jar) before installing. Now the installation folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra` has both `asca-3.0.0.jar` and `asca-3.0.1.jar`.I also see that the windows service description also has not changed(which means it has not uninstalled a existing windows service and installed new windows service).

Comment: But I think this can  be solved by uninstalltion of current installation (version 3.0.0) before installing new version installer exe file (version 3.0.1). Is this possible?, Or do you have any better solution?. Kindly help.

Comment: Happy it works now. You can add a "Execute previous uninstaller" action to the installer to get rid of the old files. I would suggest to create new questions for any further problems that are not directly related to the title.