# com.install4j.api.update.UpdateChecker is not shipped after the build if no launchers

Tags: install4j

I see that If I remove all launchers in install4j which are redundant to me as our project is webapp as a service, After doing build and executing the installer, The `i4jruntime.jar` present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Astra\.install4j` does not contain `com.install4j.api.update.UpdateChecker` class. Is it mandatory to have 
 atleast one launcher? I am using install4j 7.0.2. Because of this the working Auto update functionality ([Auto update for web app as a service with no launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047591)) has broken. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "runtime shrinking" feature in install4j. If you start your webapp with a generated service launcher, the compiler will retain all referenced classes in the runtime, including the UpdateChecker.

You can disable runtime shrinking on the "General Settings->Media File Options" step by deselecting the "Shrink runtime library and remove all unused classes" check box.